# Running an SQL query for each week in the passed year

Tags: mysql, sql, date

I need to find data for the end of each week in the passed year. Currently I have this code.

```
Select Ordnum, orddate, sls,  count(*) over () as Total 
from invoices
where shipvia = 'drop ship'

AND OrdDate between '9/28/2015' and '10/2/2015'
```

So right now that displays the data I need for a particular week. I used the count over to gather the total rows returned because in the end that is the number I need to know for each week. I need that total number for each week going back to the passed year maybe more. How can I go about doing this? Thank you!

Comment: If you want results also for weeks without any data, you'll need some kind of help table, with the dates (or week numbers.)